# How I can parse a 3.7 to 3700 int in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I need parse the list of nums with a point in the thousand in c# .

The 3.7 to 3700
The 6.45 to 6450
and if I need 5432.2 pass to 5432200 same

Tanks

Answer (score 4):

Just parse as decimal and multiply by 1000.

Comment: And then round it (using some rounding rule) and cast it to an integer.

Comment: if you parse 6.45 as decimal it would give you 645

Comment: @JoãoPauloAmorim He means to use Decimal.Parse() or Decimal.TryParse()

Comment: well, if you try to Decimal.Parse a string with "6.45" it gives you 645..

Comment: "Just parse" is probably not good enough as an answer depending on the location of OP. Different cultures can have different decimal point characters, leading to different parsing results depending on whatever the current culture is when parsing the string...

Comment: @JoãoPauloAmorim, if i try the result is expectedly 6.45. The result of parsing depends on the culture that is in effect (the current culture). So, you can't really tell what the result will be without knowing the current culture at the time of parsing (or without explicitly specifying the culture or number format used for parsing). Hence why i said "could"... ;-P

Comment: @elgonzo true fact, i just tried parsing with en-US culture and it gave me 6.45, that's a good thing to know, really didnt know about that, thanks for the knowledge

Answer (score 3):

Parse the value as a `decimal` (specifying the correct culture) and multiply it with 1000.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = "5432.2";

    if(TryParseToPermille(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out int promille))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(promille.ToString());
    }
}
```

Using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` will always interprete the dot as decimal separator and commas as thousand separators. If you want to use the current user's culture, use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` instead.

```
public static bool TryParseToPermille(string input, IFormatProvider formatProvider, out int promille)
{
    bool result = false;
    promille = 0;

    if(Decimal.TryParse(input, NumberStyles.Number, formatProvider, out decimal value))
    {
        result = true;
        value = value * 1000;
        promille = (int)Math.Truncate(value); // or "Round" or "Ceiling" or "Floor" depending on your use case
    }

    return result;
}

public static bool TryParseToPermille(string input, out int promille)
{
    return TryParseToPromille(input, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out promille);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

multiple by `1000` and convert into `int`

```
        double  num1 = 3.7;
        double num2  = 6.45;

        int num1_convert  = Convert.ToInt32(num1 * 1000);
        int num2_convert  = Convert.ToInt32(num2 * 1000);
```

Result : 
`3700`
`6450`